# inode/x-empty content-type after upload file from iOS and GoogleDrive/iCloud

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, paperclip

I have a problem with upload files from `iOS` devices and cloud storage like `Google Drive` or `iCloud` into my Ruby on Rails application. When file is uploaded from local storage or android and desktop apps everything works as should.

App technical details:

- RoR 4.2.7.1 (it was also tested after upgrade into RoR 5.0)
- Ruby 2.3.3
- Paperclip v6.1.0 (for attachments)

After saving the form I have paperclip Spoof Exception:

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 001.testing_doc.gdoc (inode/x-empty from Headers, [] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: inode/x-empty. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

Ofcourse uploaded file is not empty.

I decided to debug the issue before all paperclip stuff starts, so I check the `params` inside controller action before saving the object with paperclip:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f90c2422868 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/4w/tskhtmr14g5b4822nsdckgfm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20200214-67820-4542m9.gdoc>, @original_filename="001. Console - podstawy.gdoc", @content_type="application/vnd.google-apps.document", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[cvs_attributes][0][file]\"; filename=\"001.testing_doc.gdoc\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.google-apps.document\r\n">
```

I've checked the file inside tmp folder `/var/folders/4w/tskhtmr14g5b4822nsdckgfm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20200214-67820-4542m9.gdoc` by using `cat` program and file was empty. It should not be.

Additional thing is, that the problem exist inside our 3 different instances of application. FE of one of them is written with Angular and the rest are simply integrated views with RoR application and jQuery library.

It looks like the problem is not inside gem for attachments but, I alos decide to make some simply tests with fresh RoR applications and different combinations of gems:

- RoR 5.0, paperclip v6.0.1 - I had `Content Type Spoof` paperclip exception but file inside params was not empty. The exception was related with different thing. Content-type was correctly.
- RoR 5.2, paperclip v6.0.1 - same as above, file was not empty.
- RoR 5.2, ActiveStorage - works fine
- RoR 6.0, ActiveStorage - works fine

I will be grateful for any help, because I fight with this bug for a long time.